# Reorder the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,11$ as $a,b,c,d,e,f$ so that the sum $s=ab+cd+ef$ is as small as possible.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Prove that no smaller sum is as small as possible.

My approach:

If is arrange  by  order of the highest number to the lowest

By arranging them in that order.
$1,11,2,5,3,4$

$S=1×11+2×5+3×4$

Given $33$

Comment: There are $15$ possible sums since there are $5$ ways to pair a number with $1$, $3$ ways to pair a number with the smallest remaining number in the list, and one way to pair the final two numbers.  Your sum $1 \cdot 11 + 2 \cdot 5 + 3 \cdot 4 = 11 + 10 + 12 = 33$.  You either need to show that $33$ is the smallest of these sums or produce a smaller sum.  I suspect that $33$ is the smallest sum.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. To prove that $33$ is the smallest possible  sum you can get, just show what happens when you opt for $2 \times 11$ (in all the other cases, $11x$, with $x \in \{ 3, 4, 5 \}$, automatically gives a sum larger than $33$)

Comment: See also the answer of C. O'Neill (that I did not see while I was writing my comment).

Answer (score 6):

$11$ obviously can not be multiplied with $3,4$ or $5$, or the result would already be larger than your previously discovered series.

Taking $11\times2$, then the only choice for $5$ to be multiplied with and remain smaller than the smallest known solution is $1$. But that leaves $3\times4$, bringing the total up larger than the known total. Therefore, $11$ must be multiplied with $1$.

From there, it's simple to see that $2\times5+3\times4 \lt 2\times3+4\times5$, so the smallest solution must be $11\times1+2\times5+3\times4$, which is just the provided solution.